# Auto refresh a webpage on content update only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a webpage on my website which gets content updates every 1-60 mins (random/varies) and at first I made the webpage auto refresh using:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" >
```

However, this is very annoying when scrolling and just generally using the webpage.

I thought about using an iframe on a separate webpage like so:

```
<iframe src="output.html" width="2500" height="10000" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, again this throws up more problems with it not refreshing (if I remove the meta tags) and my original webpage height varies depending on how much data is on the page.

I'm looking for some advice / code help to get a way to only refresh the main webpage if the content is updated. (It doesn't matter if a suggested solution is in HTML, PHP or any other language)

Any suggestions or constructive comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
 - Hyflex

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
<title>data data data data data</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("style.css");
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="gradle" summary="main">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data Rank</th>
            <th scope="col">data Odds</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">AV10</th>
            <th scope="col">data Rank</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data Rank</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">Age</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data 14 Day</th>
            <th scope="col">data CSR</th>
            <th scope="col">data TSR</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data 14 Day</th>
            <th scope="col">data CSR</th>
            <th scope="col">data TSR</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data data</th>
            <th scope="col">data data</th>
            <th scope="col">data data</th>
            <th scope="col">data data</th>
            <th scope="col">data data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
            <th scope="col">data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Closest I've got thanks to a post below is:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    update_content()
    $(document).ready(function (e)
    {
        var refresher = setInterval("update_content();", 250);
    })

    function update_content()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "output.html",
            timeout: 10000,
            cache: false,
        })
            .done(function (page_html)
            {
                var newDoc = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
                if (page_html != newDoc)
                {
                    alert("LOADED");
                    var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    newDoc.write(page_html);
                    newDoc.close();

                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you Okay to use client side libraries? Like [Knockout.js](http://www.knockoutjs.com)? Its just perfect for requirement like you said.

Comment: I've had a look at it but unable to get anything working from it, the closest thing I have to what I need is the Websters code, it nearly suits my needs.

Comment: Did it really work for you? `newDoc` removes doctype declaration and html tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ask3C/

You will have to replace the path to the one of your page. Should rewrite the document every 30 seconds. It is a bit of a hack approach but if you are still using Meta Refresh - it is light years better. Give it a go. The script for jQuery library is just pulling from Google repository.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var refresher = setInterval("update_content();",30000); // 30 seconds
})

function update_content(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php", // post it back to itself - use relative path or consistent www. or non-www. to avoid cross domain security issues
      cache: false, // be sure not to cache results
    })
      .done(function( page_html ) {
        alert("LOADED");
    var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
    newDoc.write(page_html);
    newDoc.close();

    });   

}
```

Comment: I tried tweaking that for my needs but it doesn't work correctly :/

See my original post. Also I should mention my html table is rather large, for example if I set the update to 1000 (1 second) it lags the browser up pretty bad.

As the table size is so big is it possible to cycle through each table block and update ones what are different? (some lines might get removed)

Comment: How reliable is this? I have a requirement to refresh an image once a minute in a browser for monitoring an industrial process. I need to know this will not just work for a while and then fail without warning.

Comment: This works, but makes the page flash on update. Any way to repair it?

Comment: @RedClover before refreshing verify if there is a change in content from the received data, if there is a change, refresh, if not, just don't do anything, I guess

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is very common. Have you explored how twitter like feed update is working?. You have to do as follows

```
var interval = function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

        $.ajax({

            // Ajax options goes here
            success : function(data) {
                // Process Data
                // Generate HTML
                // Insert Generated HTML whereever you want in document
                interval() //Initiate next fetch
            }
        })

    }, 1000 // Interval time
    );
};
```

Note: Here I am using jQuery ajax.

Hopefully this will give an idea.

Comment: I tried the other guys code and tried to tweak it a little but it didn't work correctly, I've had a go with yours and my attempt was even worse.

Answer (score 3):

A good solution would be to use javascript and make ajax calls at set intervals. Then update whatever element with new content from your response. This way you won't have to deal with refreshes which would be very annoying.

Comment: The main webpage is just some simple html page with a table full of contents. Added example of my code. I'm not sure how to code an ajax / javascript call to do this.

Comment: @Hyflex I would suggest looking at [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and its $.ajax() function to help you make ajax calls to your server.